# Is it possible to find a recent ad in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Yesterday there was an ad displayed in the feed. How would I go about finding this ad again if I don't have any information on the company like name etc? Perhaps even viewing only sponsored posts and filtering out all the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it's not possible.**
Ads are targeted with real time bidding meaning that ads that are most likely to generate the most revenue to Facebook are displayed to you. That means that there are "infinitive" number of ads that could be displayed to you. It might be that Facebook keep a list of what ads have been displayed to you (in order to optimize what future ads might interest you) but it's not anything that they share with you.

Comment: If you [download your profile data](https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/), it includes a list of interests used to display ads for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I just find an Ad I pass like 3 days ago; and told my self I look for it latter. Just go to your face book app and tabs and look for Recent Ad Activity and there you go...

Comment: Hi, please try to improve your answer, so it will be more informative, maybe with a screenshot or steps etc. Check out [how to answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

As @screener has said, you have two sections in the downloaded archive :
- the ads you clicked on
- the subjects that generate ads for you

Answer (score -2):

Search the Ad Library – Facebook at
https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=political_and_issue_ads&country=US